# Converting a list of bytes data to string

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7

kindly suggest a method to convert a list of bytes to list of strings or any method so I can read resp data as a string , I have tried using decode but it isn't supported with below error -

> Unresolved attribute reference 'decode' for class 'list'

```
resp = [b'\r\x1b[2K\x1b[39m[00479650ms][INFO][MBED_DC]: dc_func:230 Waiting \r\n',
    b'\x1b[0m\r\n', b'AT+BOOTARG=TRACE=ON\r\r\n']
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: `decode` is not a method of a list, but of each bytes object inside the list. Iterate over the list, decoding each element as you go. There are a few ways to do that, namely `map` and list comprehensions.

Comment: `resp_dec = list(map(lambda x: x.decode("utf-8"), resp))`

Comment: thanks it converts but stops after first item can u kindly tell how can i fix it resp = [b'\r\x1b[2K\x1b[39m[00479650ms][INFO][MBED_DC]: dc_func:230 Waiting \r\n',
        b'\x1b[0m\r\n', b'AT+BOOTARG=TRACE=ON\r\r\n']

resp_decoded = list(map(lambda i: i.decode('utf8'), resp))
print(resp_decoded)
final_str = "".join(resp_decoded)
print(final_str)  ==> [00479650ms][INFO][MBED_DC]: dc_func:230 Waiting , here AT+BOOTARG=TRACE=ON gets skipped

Comment: Check your input / output. It shouldn't stop, and in your code example there's no correlation between what you wrote is your input and the output. So I have reason to believe your input is not exactly what you wrote in the question.

Comment: thanks shev seems my ide was the culprit was not displaying output properly when tried with direct terminal it worked

Answer (score 2):

Decode it:

```
resp = [b'\r\x1b[2K\x1b[39m[00479650ms][INFO][MBED_DC]: dc_func:230 Waiting \r\n',
    b'\x1b[0m\r\n', b'AT+BOOTARG=TRACE=ON\r\r\n']
decode_list = []
for item in resp:
    decode_list.append(item.decode("utf-8"))
```

Time compare:

```
exp1 = """
resp = [b'item1',b'item2']
new_list = []
for item in resp:
    new_list.append(item.decode("utf-8"))
"""

exp2 = """
resp = [b'item1',b'item2']
new_list = [item.decode("utf-8") for item in resp]
"""

exp3 = """
resp = [b'item1',b'item2']
resp_dec = list(map(lambda x: x.decode("utf-8"), resp))
"""

timeit(exp1, number=1000)
timeit(exp2, number=1000)
timeit(exp3, number=1000)
```

exp3 seems more 'elegant' though it is slower.

Outputs:

```
   exp1 --> 0.0002586000000000116
   exp2 --> 0.00029969999999999997
   exp3 --> 0.0004574999999999996
```

Comment: had already tried this -- it fails with list' object has no attribute 'decode'

Comment: @Lp-Tester
This is per item in the list, not on the list itself.
As mentioned above decode is not a method of a list.

Comment: thanks David it works for single item it there any way I can get all strings at once currently it gets stopped at [00479650ms][INFO][MBED_DC]: dc_func:230 Waiting 
 only , the next at+bootarg doesn't get converted

Comment: I just love a micro-benchmark run once on a tiny sample set with insignificant difference to claim something is "faster".

Comment: @shevron
This is mainly to share with the community the pros and cons.
You are right maybe it is insignificant for some small sample,
but for larger inputs etc... others might considered it.

Comment: david u rock \.../

Answer (score 0):

Use map to decode each item in the list and map it all to a new list:

```py
resp_decoded = list(map(lambda i: i.decode('utf8'), resp))
```

Comment: this doesn't give a list, but a map object

Comment: @mcsoini correct, and of course your suggestion above solves that :)

Comment: thanks it converts but stops after first item can u kindly tell how can i fix it resp = [b'\r\x1b[2K\x1b[39m[00479650ms][INFO][MBED_DC]: dc_func:230 Waiting \r\n', b'\x1b[0m\r\n', b'AT+BOOTARG=TRACE=ON\r\r\n'] resp_decoded = list(map(lambda i: i.decode('utf8'), resp)) print(resp_decoded) final_str = "".join(resp_decoded) print(final_str) ==> [00479650ms][INFO][MBED_DC]: dc_func:230 Waiting , here AT+BOOTARG=TRACE=ON gets skipped